# How to enable multi-dex option for Android in Unity3D?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

On building with Unity, I am getting an error:

```
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 78849; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
```

But I can't figure out how to explicitly tell Unity to use multi dex.

Comment: is unity like a plugin to android or a seperate version of android

Comment: I suppose that you can export android project and enable it manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For activation multidex on Unity follow a 3 simple steps:

[image]

**1)** Use Gradle build system:

```
Unity -> File -> Build Settings -> Build System -> Gradle.
```

**2)** Check in "Сustom Gradle Template":

```
Player Setting... -> Publish Settings -> Check in "Сustom Gradle Template"
```

**3)** Change mainTemplate.gradle file:

Open file from path: *Assets\Plugins\Android\mainTemplate.gradle*

Add folow code:

```
android 
{
   ...
   defaultConfig
   {
       multiDexEnabled true
       ...
    }
}
```

Additional information:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. It works perfectly fine in the latest versions of Unity, where gradle build is the default option.

Comment: Easy and works like a charm. I was trying other solutions (ex from developer.android) with no effects and finally this worked.

Answer (score 12):

I'd suggest to check official Unity3D forum regarding this question:

[Multidex Support on Android](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/multidex-support-on-android.325429/)

And Q/A's from there: [Too many method references when I export android build](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/816708/too-many-method-references-when-i-export-android-b.html)

Here's reply from Unity's official:

> So the biggest reason we have not added support for this in Unity is because it doesn't work. Or rather it usually creates more problems than it solves. Unless you are targeting only modern versions of Android I would suggest you do everything in your power including stripping and proguarding your code before you take the route of multi-dex.
>
> If you don't believe me just checkout the *known* limitations of the multi-dex library at Googles developer page:
> https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations

So conclusion is to do all best to shrink number of methods to stay within 65K limit. For example, if you use google-play-services.jar, you can replace it with only required submodules of it.

There's also discussion around exporting to Android Studio and build the project there but, apparently, it didn't work out due to dex issue.

Also, I advocate to read [this](https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71#.i5vovwcq2) write-up regarding DEX issue.

I hope, it helps. Good luck!