# How to fix in Unity "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.workers$actionfacade"

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile-ad-mediation

I am working with adMob mediation in Unity. I have integrated inMobi and Unity ads network. After integrating them I am getting the following error "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.workers$actionfacade". Without integrating inMobi and Unity ads the build is successful. I just don't understand what is the problem

I looked up to a similar question in Unity forum https://forum.unity.com/threads/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks-workers-actionfacade.958112/ and tried solving by correctly entering the password,restarting Unity, creating seperate build file folder,etc but unfortunately nothing is working.

I saw similar question in stackOverflow, but they were for flutter,Cordova,etc and not Unity[image: ScreenShot of the error]

Some of the content of the Editor Log file near the error:

```
Note: C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70023 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:445)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:348)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70023 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.y0.a(:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.K.a(:56)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.K$h.a(:5)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(:15)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(:38)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:87)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:30)
    ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeDexRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
0x00007ff67f67736c (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff67f67d509 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff67fe6f193 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff680d705ba (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff67f80750d (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x000001e5a38a2f0b (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x000001e5a38a2e5b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x000001e5a38a28d0 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x000001e5a38a2795 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x000001e65b81a623 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.GradleInvokationException:ParseAndShowException ()
0x000001e7272b2cf3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext)
0x000001e6a04ee4ab (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget,string,string,string,string,string,string,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
0x000001e6a050f94b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
0x000001e6a050f291 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
0x000001e6a050f589 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007fff733fe640 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2812] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff73382ad2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff7338bb2f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff67f5c2be4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff67f5be251 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff680e83321 (Unity) CallMono
0x00007ff680e8991d (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
0x00007ff680e857d3 (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild
0x00007ff680e84370 (Unity) DoBuildPlayer
0x00007ff680e79e45 (Unity) BuildPlayer
0x00007ff680458a05 (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00007ff68042b5ac (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x000001e72728408a (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
0x000001e72728386b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
0x000001e7272806db (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
0x000001e72718bf93 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform)
0x000001e727174003 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x000001e727165acb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
0x000001e6bf072b73 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEngine.Rect)
0x000001e6bf0728e3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEngine.Rect)
0x000001e6bf0679d3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
0x000001e554868108 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x000001e5548e56db (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x000001e7271576bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
0x000001e727157543 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
0x000001e727156d9b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x000001e727154183 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x000001e6b7a9b12b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x000001e6b7a89ab8 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x000001e727151983 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000001e6b7a87d8e (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x000001e6b7a87883 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000001e6b7a8d833 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x000001e6b7a8bee3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
0x000001e6b7a8be2b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x000001e6b7a87b13 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000001e6b7a871e3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x000001e6b7a8705b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x000001e6b8b2205b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
0x000001e6b8b21afb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x000001e6b8b218bf (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x000001e6b8b217db (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
0x000001e6b8b2165d (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x000001e6b8b2170e (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007fff733fe640 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2812] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff73382ad2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff7338bb2f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff67f5c2be4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff67f5be251 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff67f5b8615 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff67e89b23a (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff67f9ae0f6 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff67fe9a8a2 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00007ff67f9adfe2 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00007ff67fe9b8c9 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff67fe95a08 (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007ffff24ae858 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007ffff24ae299 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff67fe74d76 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff67fe78af6 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff6819a5682 (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffff1fd7034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffff2c22651 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[
Note: C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70023 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:445)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:348)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70023 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.y0.a(:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.K.a(:56)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.K$h.a(:5)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(:15)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(:38)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:87)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:30)
    ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeDexRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
```

Comment: You need to enable multidex or proguard.

Comment: I hope you were able to fix this using Multidex. If not please comment I will provide step to step guide

Comment: Yeah please tell @RajSuvariya. I was busy with someother stuff actually

Comment: @ChethanCV take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55960144/7454155

Answer (score 0):

The Java code used in an Android app is compiled into DEX files in the APK. There are certain limitations for Android applications when compiling to API levels before 21 (Android Lollipop), which is what the error `Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file` is about. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex on how to configure Android Studio to deal with these limitations. Hopefully you can apply the same configuration to your environment.